# Problems building a GUI which will compare algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, user-interface

I'm looking to build a GUI that will let the user randomly populate an array and then compare the time it takes to sort by bubble sort, insertion sort and selection sort. i have the code for the 3 algorithms but i'm struggling to put it all together and compare it using System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good idea, but I think you need to give more details about the implementation (e.g. code) and a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

You may separate the algorihtms in 3 different methods. Then you may try something as :

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
bubbleSort(Arrays.copy(array,array.length));
syso("It took " +System.currentTimeMillis() - now);

now = System.currentTimeMillis();
selectinSort(Arrays.copy(array,array.length));
syso("It took " +System.currentTimeMillis() - now);

//and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Break this into a couple tasks.  If you haven't done GUI dev here's a great place to get your first window going:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Keep it simple. Don't get hung up in the layout unless you have to.  Gridlayout works nice for simple stuff.

Add either multiple textboxes to allow user to enter data or add a table.  Add a single button that will collect the users data and kick off all your algorithms.

Then add a textarea with for your results.